# Arduino Nano TX and RX LEDs Not Lighting Up During Upload

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, servo

I'm encountering a problem with my Arduino Nano board. When I attempt to upload sketches to the board using the Arduino IDE, only the Power LED lights up, and the TX and RX LEDs remain inactive. I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including reinstalling drivers, using different USB cables, and trying different USB ports on my computer. Despite these efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Board Details:

- Arduino Nano with ATmega microcontroller
- Power LED is lit when the board is connected
- "L" LED blinks rapidly during upload
- TX and RX LEDs are not lighting up during upload

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- Reinstalled Arduino IDE and drivers
- Tried multiple USB cables and ports
- Verified COM port selection in Arduino IDE
- Checked USB-Serial converter chip for damage

I'm reaching out to the community for help and guidance. Has anyone else encountered this issue? What further steps should I take to diagnose and resolve this problem? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does the program upload correctly?

Comment: Were there any error messages during upload? Have you tried programming another Arduino using the same cables & IDE (even an Uno, in case you don't have another Nano)? Can you tell whether the Nano got programmed? If you have an Arduino that is already programmed, and talks to the serial port, have you tested whether you can read or write to that one from your IDE's serial terminal?

Comment: There are many varieties of "Nanos" with different processor types which may require a special configuration of the IDE, selection of a bootloader type etc. Here, for example, is one using a "near" clone of the ATmega328P chip: https://robot-r-us.com.sg/p/lgt8f328p-more-capable-than-arduino-nano-v3-0. Can you provide a link to the one you have purchased?

Answer (score 1):

They many times will not light because of the bit pattern being sent and the short time the bit is active to light the LED. If it is uploading code without errors you are good to go.  Quick test, If not try another Arduino and see if it uploads or not. If not it is your computer or a bad cable otherwise it is a bad Arduino.